# Is it possible a pipeline of loop been created using Publisher and Subscriber in Swift Combine framework?

Tags: swift, combine

The following code doesn't work with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

```
func publisherLoopExample() {
    let publisher = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
    
    let subscriber = publisher.sink { [weak publisher] received in
        guard let publisher = publisher else { return }
        publisher.send(received)
        print("received \(received)")
    }
    
    publisher.send("1")
}
```

Questions:

1. Why EXC_BAD_ACCESS raised?
2. Is there a concern that in the subscriber, it sends data to the original publisher so it could be a loop?

Comment: Everything here happens synchronously. `send` invokes `sink`, which invokes `send`, which invokes `sink`, and so forth.. you created a tight loop.

Comment: You are running into the problem for which this site is named: a stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Q1:
Reviewing the callstack, it does repeat the sink for lots of times, which might cause a overflow.

Q2:
According to the above, yes, and it should be avoid.